# Where can I find the list of Prettier's default rules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier

Suppose that the following code is given as input

```js
message='Hello, '+"World";


console.log( message );
```

Prettier generates following code

```js
message = "Hello, " + "World";

console.log(message);
```

Spaces are inserted before and after `+` operator. But I can't find a document that mentions this behavior.

Is there a complete list of Prettier's default rules (especially about non-configurable ones)?

Answer (score 1):

The well-documented rules happen to be the [configurable ones](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html). However, if you're looking to explore everything prettier does, it may be worthwhile looking at the [unit tests](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/tree/master/tests/js). Specifically, each folder has a `__snapshots__` folder inside that contains a config, input, and output.